# How to close a modal in slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api, apex, slack-commands

I am using apex to invoke the modal in slack and a bit confused on how to use the response_action for closing it.

```
{
  "response_action": "clear"
}
```

Do I need to make an HTTP request and if yes what will be the endpoint and what will be the structure of JSON?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make any Api call to close the modal , you have to send back 200 to close the current view.If you want to close all views you can
return {
"response_action": "clear"
}

Answer (score -1):

All I had to do was send back an HTTP 200 because I had only one view open but if multiple views are there we can use

```
{
  "response_action": "clear"
}
```

Referred to the documentation here- https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#close_current_view